# How to Display different controls (CheckBox, RadioButton or TextBox) based on returned parameter in ASP.NET Razor View and Save response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, controls

I am building a CRUD application (Multiple Choice answers for a form), the response to each question can be list of checkboxes, radio buttons, textboxes or mixture of 2 controls. Please How do I display the CheckBox in the Razor View and How do I display 2 types of Controls side by side and Save user response?

Here is my Model:

```
  public class Question
  {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; } 
    public bool HasMultiAnswers { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfAnswers { get; set; }
    public double TotalPoint { get; set; } 
    public String InputTypes { get; set; } 
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; } 
    public double point { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = _context.Questions.ToList();

        var questionModel = new List<Question>();

        questions.ForEach(q =>
        {
            var model = new Question
            {
                Id = q.Id,
                Title = q.Title,
                Details = q.Details,
                HasMultiAnswers = q.HasMultiAnswers,
                NumberOfAnswers = q.NumberOfAnswers,
                InputTypes = q.InputTypes, //New Line 
                Options = _context.Options.Where(f => f.point == 10).ToList()
            };
            questionModel.Add(model);
        });
        return View(questionModel);
    }
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    <div class="jumbotron">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            var inputTypes = Model[i].InputTypes.Split(',').ToList();

            <p>@Model[i].Details</p>

            for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Options.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < inputTypes.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (inputTypes[x] == "TextBox")
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => Model[i].Options[j].Details, new { @class = "form" })
                    }
                    else if (inputTypes[x] == "CheckBox")
                    {
                       // @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => Model[i].Options[j].Details, new { @class = "form" }) // - Throws Error
                    }
                    else if (inputTypes[x] == "RadioButton")
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(u => Model[i].Options[j].Details, new { @class = "form" })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: The checkbox option should probably be parsed to a boolean value in order to work with the CheckBoxFor. I don't understand your second question. What do you mean show two controls side by side. You mean something different from just using div with col-md-6 for example?

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis So how do you parse it? My Second question is, some response will require 3 radio buttons and say 2 text box instead of just checboxes alone or radio button alone ot textbox alone.